# Postgres Materialize Node completing faster than its sub-node

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was analyzing a slow postgresql database query and I noticed something that seemed quite odd to me (I'm new at analysing queries in postgres). The actual time for the Materialize node both starts and finishes before its sub node.

```
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=300.28..698.21 rows=1 width=54) (actual time=180.547..11022.591 rows=166 loops=1)
          Join Filter: (mytable1.category_id = mytable2.category_id)
          ->  Index Scan using mytable2_p_category_id on mytable2  (cost=0.00..3.48 rows=15 width=4) (actual time=0.012..0.037 rows=15 loops=1)
          ->  Materialize  (cost=300.28..694.51 rows=1 width=54) (actual time=12.036..734.653 rows=166 loops=15)
                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=300.28..694.50 rows=1 width=54) (actual time=180.520..11016.887 rows=166 loops=1)
```

Does anyone know when and where you might expect this to happen?

In case it's relevant our postgres server is running version 9.1

Thanks

Comment: Note the loops: `734.653 * 15 = 11019.795`.

Comment: That makes sense. Any idea if this is just normal operation for reporting of Materialized loop times? For that matter is that how I should try and read any nodes with loops as a value > 1. -- Scrap that second question, it wouldn't really work for the inner Nested Loop.

Comment: There is a difference between the estimated {rows,time} and the actual ones. Are the statistics for this table up-to-date ? -->> `VACUUM ANALYZE mytable2;`.

Comment: I did a general "VACUUM ANALYZE" of the database without specifying a table. I didn't specifically VACUUM ANALYZE of mytable2 individually though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Denis pointed out in the comments (so I can't give him the tick of approval) it would seem that the actual time for the Materialize node is probably best read in terms of `loops * actual time`

So in this example that would be:
`Start - (12.036 * 15) = 180.54`
`End - (734.653 * 15) = 11019.795`

Browsing online I found other examples of looped Materialize statements being reported this way also.

So I guess the answer to the question of "when and where" is almost always when your Materialize node is being looped over.

So unless someone who knows better chimes in I'll just make this the answer for now.